# How can you add a class for the title?

Tags: javascript, class

```
function showPromptMessage() {
    swal({
        title: "Describe your edit",
        type: "input",
        showCancelButton: true,
        closeOnConfirm: false,
        animation: "slide-from-top",
        inputPlaceholder: "Write something"
    }, function (inputValue) {
        if (inputValue === false) return false;
        if (inputValue === "") {
            swal.showInputError("You need to write something!"); return false
        }
        swal("Saved successfully");
    });
}
```

Comment: Please edit your text and add a question to it. Now there is only a piece of code without any explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Add to your css:

```
h2.swal2-title{
   color: blue; 
   /*Whatever you need*/
}
```

For more information visit: https://limonte.github.io/sweetalert2/